# Excel - How to Delete Cells based on Conditions

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I am wondering if there is an easy way to do the following:

I have an excel spreadsheet.

One column, let's call it COLUMN ONE has two possible values.  "Not Visible Individually" and "Catalog, Search" are the two possible values.

The column to the right, let's call it COLUMN TWO, has inventory numbers.

I would like to be able to delete all values in COLUMN TWO that have the value "Catalog, Search" in COLUMN ONE to the left.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Insert a filter.
2. Filter on "Catalog, Search" in column one. Only "Catalog, Search" should appear now.
3. Select the values in column two (click the first cell then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>) and press <kbd>Delete</kbd>.
4. Remove the filter.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah You're welcome! Be aware that stack overflow is more for programming than for software usage. Consider using [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) next time, which is for usage of software and hardware :)

Answer (score 1):

Filter COLUMN ONE for "Catalog, Search" and then select the shown cells in COLUMN TWO and press the Del key.  You can remove the filter afterwards.